# Netrw and other windows opened at the same time: no window toggling

Tags: vim, netrw

When I open a netrw window and any other window (`:new` or help window, for example) at the same time, I can't toggle between those two windows using `<c-w><c-w>` or any other keys. I can even open a new window with `:new`, and still only be able to toggle between all the windows except the netrw window. However, I can focus on netrw window if all the other windows are closed. Why is that, is it a proper behavior, and is there a way to have normal window toggling in such situation?

Comment: cannot be reproduced here.. moving cursor from one to the other works.. btw, what do you mean "toggle"?

Comment: I mean changing active window from one window to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is not the proper behavior.

Check if you have any mappings that could cause interferences with `:map <c-w>`.

Check if it happens with the latest version of [netrw (v147)](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1075). If it still happens, you could try to gradually comment your `.vimrc` and remove your plugins and see if this problem stops.